# how to write repeat patterns

Tags: sed, awk

A file has list of unique "tags" and "values" separated by tab. I want to repeat the tag according to the given value. Example of input file:

tag  value

```
AAAAA   2
BBBBB   1
CCCCC   3
DDDDD   5
```

Expected output File

```
AAAAA 
AAAAA 
BBBBB 
CCCCC 
CCCCC 
CCCCC 
DDDDD 
DDDDD 
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
```

Could you please tell me the awk/sed command. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative version for GNU awk:

```
awk '{while($2--) print $1}'
```

This is not a good problem to solve with sed. You need to replace a number `n` with `n` `1`'s (for example 3 with 111) and print the word as you consume these `1`'s.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=$2;i++) print $1}' file
AAAAA
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
CCCCC
CCCCC
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
```

It loops the number of times found in column `#2`, then print the word in column `#1`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `perl` alternate:

```
$ perl -ane 'print "$F[0]\n"x$F[1]' file
AAAAA
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
CCCCC
CCCCC
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/seq \2 | sed c\1/e' file
```

Split the line into arguments for `seq` and `sed` commands and evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Doing arithmetic in `sed` is a pain, so I would avoid that. `awk` and `perl` are good choices, you can also straightforwardly do it with `bash`:

```
while read tag value; do
  while ((value--)); do 
    printf "%s\n" "$tag"
  done
done < infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
while read tag value; do while ((value--)); do printf "%s\n" "$tag"; done; done < infile
```

Output:

```
AAAAA
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
CCCCC
CCCCC
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
DDDDD
```